# Data of vehicle routing problem time windowed

Tags: java, timefold

I'm new to Timefold. I use the example that already exists in QuickStarts. My goal is to use this program to solve my own problem with capacity constraints, but the problem is that I don't know where I need to change the data properly.

i try to change the data exists in "VehicleRouteDemoResource" but it does not work.
Where can i find the file that contain the data needed for this problem to solve it?
thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to solve CVRPTW by adding capacities to the [vehicle-routing-time-windows quickstart](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/vehicle-routing-time-windows).

In fact, you need to combine it with the [vehicle-routing-capacity quickstart](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/vehicle-routing-capacity) next to it.

The data sets are truly generated in the VehicleRouteDemoResource; have a loot at the [DemoData enum](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/blob/stable/use-cases/vehicle-routing-capacity/src/main/java/org/acme/vehiclerouting/rest/VehicleRouteDemoResource.java#L41-L43) and its parameters that define the vehicle capacity and customer demands.